# Changes in NSManagedObject does not save in to CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two methods to save and load NSManagedObject (updated to original):

```
-(void) saveToCoreData: (TeamManagedObject *)teamSet{


    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelDebug);

    if(!teamSet) {
        self.teamSet = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TeamManagedObject" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    } else {
        self.teamSet = teamSet;

    }


    [self.teamSettings enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [self.teamSet setValue:obj forKey:key];
    }];

    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&saveError];
}

-(id)load:(TeamManagedObject *)managedObject {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([TeamManagedObject class], &count);



    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
        NSString *value = [managedObject valueForKey:key];


        if (value) {
            [self setObject:value forKey:key];
        }

    }

self.teamSet = managedObject;
    free(properties);
    return self;
}
```

1) call method [self save:nil] - object creates and saves to CoreData correctly. (value is correct after having app restarted)

2) restarting app and calling load method - it was loaded correctly

3) calling save [self save:object] method with loaded object  - it looks like saved, but only before app was restarted... after app restarting, object have an old value...

Where is the mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you make a fetch from CoreData after application is restarted? Do you have the correct reference of the managedObject?

Comment: Yes, I get object from tableViewController with data, based on fetchedResultController. Reference is correct...

Comment: Please post the original code. There are spelling mistakes in the code you posted.